# Форматирование значений из sqlite таблицы в python (pytelegrambotapi)

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Создаю телеграм бота на python с помощью pytelegrambotapi. Столкнулся с проблемой вывода. Ниже данные которые я получаю из базы данных. Соответственно вопрос в том как убрать лишние скобки, а именно [(' ... ',)].

```
id:[('320905252',)]
⛩[('imfamous',)]
```

Код вывода:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'id:' + str(db.get_id(message.from_user.id)) + '\n⛩' + 
                str(db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id)))
```

При этом если выводить только значение из базы данных (без текста в "" и '') то значение будет *без скобок*.
**Пробовал такой формат**, получаю такой же результат со скобками:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"id {db.get_id(message.from_user.id)}")
```

Прикладываю SQL - запросы:

```
"""Получаем user_id"""
def get_id(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `user_id` FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()

"""Получаем nickname"""
def get_nickname(self, nickname):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `nickname` FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (nickname,)).fetchone()
```

Comment: Значит вы такое значение возвращаете из `db.get_id`, стопудов там просто `fetchall` вызывается, вместо `fetchone` с возвращением одного значения -- `ID`. Т.е. то, что вы сейчас делаете это костыль, для обхода неправильного заполнения таблицы. Если исправите возврат значения `db.get_id`, то проблема будет решена, а как это сделать я выше написал. Приложите, кст, как выглядит функция `db.get_id`

Comment: @gil9red Изменил на fetchone, получил вот такое значение: id: ('320905252',) - Запрашивал только db.get_id. Код sql запроса:     """Получаем user_id"""
    def get_id(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `user_id` FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()

Comment: Я еще писал что нужно брать одно значение. Т.е. `return self.cursor.execute("SELECT user_id FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()[0]`

Comment: @gil9red Все работает, спасибо большое. Изменил на выборку одного значения. Помогло!

Comment: Оформите сами ответ с решением :)

Comment: @gil9red попытался!)

Comment: Кст, лучше `"""Получаем user_id"""` переносить под функцию, так делается документирование функций и классов: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С решением данной проблемы помог [gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red)!
Необходимо вызывать fetchone с возвращением одного значения -- ID.

Была ошибка в sql-запросе, ниже исправленный вариант:

```
"""Получаем user_id"""
def get_id(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `user_id` FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()[0]
```